# How to install with yum in CentOS over a https Repo?

Tags: centos, yum

I would like to install with yum, `yum install -y yum-utils`, this package but my company's policy is not to allow http links. The yum is looking to this link for the Repos : `http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=8&arch=x86_64&repo=AppStream&infra=stock` but this link is not https, so I cannot install with yum nothing.

Do you know any https Repo links?

Comment: How are you installing packages with `yum` to begin with?

Comment: 8 , mirror list  https://www.centos.org/download/mirrors/ ............. Choose a https mirror, e.g. https://mirror.netzwerge.de/centos/ ........ You can also download the package "from https" https://mirror.netzwerge.de/centos/8/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/yum-utils-4.0.18-4.el8.noarch.rpm ..... and install with  `dnf install ./yum-utils-4.0.18-4.el8.noarch.rpm` .... ( No (new) dependencies.

Comment: @NasirRiley you are right, I 've forgotten that Fedora-CentOS are using now dnf, but I have exactly the same problem with dnf too.

Comment: @xmaze It isn't that. One can use `yum` or `dnf`. If you can't use repos that have http, then how are you installing any packages from that repo considering that many of them come from there?

Comment: @NasirRiley It is only a test PC to check docker, so until now I did not install something, I am trying to install docker but I cannot.

Comment: @KnudLarsen Hi, it is not working, I have the same error. So I downloaded the repo file, I disabled all repos from dnf and the I could install it manually. Then I added in dnf the Docker Repository, which is https, but when I try to install Docker, I have the problem : `cannot install the best candidate for the job
  - nothing provides container-selinux >= 2:2.74 needed by docker` So I think I need the repos to resolve the missing packages.

Comment: If you disable all of the repos, then that means that you can't install any of the dependencies that may come from them. You need to add repos that use SSL (https) if that is necessary. That is the only way to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Because the policy of my company is to deny the access to non-https sources. I have disabled all the Repos.
First, find all the repos `$ dnf repolist`
Second disable all the repos with http address `$  sudo dnf config-manager --set-disabled YourRepoName`
and the you are free to find any .rpm packet in the web and install it manually, like `dnf install ./myRpmFile.rpm`